# How to escape single quote in input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `input` whose value I want to get when it's checked. It has a single quote in the value.

When I run my JS I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .Oiseaux d'eau"

```js
$('.group_oiseau').on('change', function() {
  /*var group_oiseau = $('input[type=checkbox][name=group_oiseau]:checked').attr('value');*/

  $("." + $(this).find('input').val()).each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('hidden')) {
      $(this).removeClass('hidden');
      console.log($(this).hasClass('hidden'));
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('hidden');
      console.log($(this).hasClass('hidden'));
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox group_oiseau">
  <input type="checkbox"  class="grey checkbox" value="Oiseaux d'eau" name="group_oiseau[]" required>
  Oiseaux d'eau
  <div class="checkbox-cust"></div>
</label>
```

Comment: `"When i try that i get this error in console"` - what you've posted is valid HTML. We need to see the JavaScript, too.

Comment: Is it possible for you to change the value in code? Then you could set value to `Oiseaux d&apos;eau`

Comment: i posted the script.i tried  Oiseaux d&apos;eau and Oiseaux d&#39;eau

Comment: CSS class name can be only alphanumeric plus `-` and `_`

Comment: With this `$("."+$(this).find('input').val()).each(function(){ ` you are looking for elements with class name `Oiseaux d'eau`. I don't think this is your wanted behaviour..

Comment: @TomMarienfeld how should i do that ?

Comment: Sanitise the class name when you assign it, and in this code when you try to select it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It feels like you're taking the wrong approach but its unclear what you're trying to do with this code.

Comment: what i want to do is to hide or show option elements in selects that has the same class as the checked checkbox !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use JQuery to look for all `inputs` with type `checkbox` and then run the `each()` function.

```js
$('.group_oiseau').on('change', function() {
  /*var group_oiseau = $('input[type=checkbox][name=group_oiseau]:checked').attr('value');*/

$.each($('input[type=checkbox]'),function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('hidden')) {
      $(this).removeClass('hidden');
      console.log($(this).hasClass('hidden'));
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('hidden');
      console.log($(this).hasClass('hidden'));
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox group_oiseau">
  <input type="checkbox"  class="grey checkbox" value="Oiseaux d'eau" name="group_oiseau[]" required>
  Oiseaux d'eau
  <div class="checkbox-cust"></div>
</label>
```

Comment: what i want to do is to hide or show option elements in selects that has the same class as the checked checkbox !!

Answer (score 1):

```js
let value = "Oiseaux d'eau";
String(value).replace(/'/g,'&quot;');
```

when you convert the single quote to html entity the browser will show you a single quote

Answer (score 1):

Fix your name attribute a little, remove subscript `[]` if not in use:

```
<input type="checkbox"  class="grey checkbox" value="Oiseaux d'eau" name="group_oiseau" required>
```

Then this JQuery code will work fine:

```
// Get value of radio which is checked
var value = $('input[name=group_oiseau]:checked').val();

// Print that value in the console
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments so far it seems that what you are trying to achieve is not really the escaping of an apostrophe but rather the showing and hiding of elements based on checkbox selection. If these dependent elements are children or siblings then you can do this with just CSS. No JS required:

```css
label {display:inline-block; border:1px dotted grey; vertical-align:top;}
.checkbox-cust {display:none;}
input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .checkbox-cust {display:block;}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox group_oiseau">
     <input type="checkbox"  class="grey checkbox" value="Oiseaux d'eau" name="group_oiseau[]" required>
        Oiseaux d'eau
     <div class="checkbox-cust">custom stuff 1</div>
 </label>
 <label class="checkbox group_2">
     <input type="checkbox"  class="grey checkbox" value="test" name="test" required>
        test
     <div class="checkbox-cust">custom stuff 2</div>
 </label>
```